# count number of sessions in connect-redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have been struggling to count the number of users or session ids, when using connect-redis for sessions. I've referred to this: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#users-online

```
var express = require('express');
//var redis = require('redis');
//var db = redis.createClient();
var app = express();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);


app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        db: 2,
        pass: 'RedisPASS'
    }),
    secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var ua = req.headers['user-agent'];
    db.zadd('online', Date.now(), ua, next); 
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var min = 60 * 1000;
    var ago = Date.now() - min;
    db.zrevrangebyscore('online', '+inf', ago, function(err, users){
        if (err) return next(err);
        req.online = users;
        next();
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    db.zadd('online', Date.now(), req.sessionID, next);

});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.online.length + ' users online');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Obviously, the above code does not understand the variable `db` as there is no explicit `redis.createClient();` ... Does connect-redis do the `redis.createClient` internally ?

Please help on how to count the number of session ids with connect-redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, connect-redis does use redis.createClient() internally if you only provide it with credentials like you have above. You can also pass it a client directly.

```
var redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, "127.0.0.1", { auth_pass: "RedisPASS" });
redisClient.select(2);

app.use(express.session({
    store: new RedisStore({
         client: redisClient
    }),
    secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
}));
```

To get the number of sessions you'll want to query redis for the set of keys matching that key prefix. For connect-redis this is "sess:".

```
redisClient.keys("sess:*", function(error, keys){
    console.log("Number of active sessions: ", keys.length);
});
```

As they state in the redis documentation, the keys command takes linear time so in large systems it's not a good idea to query this frequently. You'd be better off keeping a separate counter that you increment when a user signs in and decrement when a user signs out.

Comment: So "a separate counter" would for instance be a Redis keyvalue that does not expire?