# How to count online users using analytics in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I was trying to count online users on my site using analytics.. but I didn't find any solution for it.. can anyone help me out?

```
##totalCtrl = {};


var totalActiveUser = (req, res, next) => {
    TotalUser.find({
    activeCount: 0
})
.exec()
.then(users => {  
  count()  
  res.status(200).json({
    status: true
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  res.json(err);
});
};
```

schema for this:

```
var totalSchema = new Schema({

dragCount: {
type: Number,
default: 0
   },
activeCount: {
type: Number,
default: 0
 },
```

Comment: socket.io is better solution for online users status.

Comment: hy, Is there any other solution without using socket.io

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726110

Answer (score 0):

You can get "online users" only if use websockets or something similar otherwise it more like visitors or views count. So need get active socket connection count.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying..can you plz share any idea about how can i count online user with socket connection